# Using a switch statement without case keyword

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm looking at [this code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/Dispatch.h#L297) and I see a `switch` statement but there is no `case` keyword within the `switch`, so it seems in all cases, only the `default` case will be executed. If my understanding of this is correct, what is the point of everything above `default`?

Comment: It's probably a macro, which includes the `case` keyword already.

Comment: The `AT_PRIVATE_CASE_TYPE` part is most likely a macro "hiding" the case label.

Comment: Yep.  `AT_PRIVATE_CASE_TYPE` is [a macro that includes `case`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/Dispatch.h#L51).  Macros sure make code harder to read, don't they?

Comment: @DrewDormann Oh I see. I should have looked at the individual function, though I was thinking they would just include the "case" keyword before getting into the function

Comment: @student010101 **Try your hardest** to avoid C++ macros.  You're not the only one to get confused trying to read code with macros sprinkled about.

Comment: Why does macros allow you to include the case keyword in the function?

Comment: @student010101 macros allow almost everything, since they work as simple text replacement before the code is actually compiled.

Comment: @student010101 macros are **not** a function.  They simply employ a text "search/replace" within your code, before compilation ever begins.  They are not subject to any rules of the C++ language or grammar.

Comment: Ahh I see. I think I've gotten used to seeing them as a regular function and not a 'replace'.